# how to check version by using xargs command in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, xargs

Please consider the following scenario:

```
$ find / -type f -name httpd
/opt/httpd.bin/httpd
/etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd
/usr/sbin/httpd
......
```

I'd like to check each and everyone of the results using the -version option like:

```
/usr/sbin/httpd -version
```

But I cannot write the xargs command, is it feasible? 
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xargs to check the version like this:

```
find ./ -type f -name httpd | xargs -n1 -I{} bash -c "{} --version"
```

But I would not recommended, it's cumbersome

You can use:

```
find ./ -type f -name httpd -exec {} --version \; -print
```

(with print being optional)

On a side note, make sure that you really want to execute those all the files, /etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd may not know what --version means, some of them may not be executable.

Answer (score 2):

`xargs` isn't really the right tool for the job, a `for` loop would work though:

```
for httpd in $(find / -type f -name httpd)
do
    $httpd --version
done
```

If you have thousands of `httpd`s then you might run into a problem with the length of the `$(find...)` output but you probably bigger problems on your hands if you have that many `httpd`s.